# Sorting a set of CSS selectors on the basis of specificity

Tags: javascript, dom, css-selectors, css-specificity

How can a set of CSS selectors be sorted on the basis of CSS specificity in a JS function?

```
function SortByCssSpecificity(input_array_of_css_selectors) {
  ...
  return sorted_array_of_css_selectors;
}
```

Comment: Well, while calculating the specificity will be easy, parsing the simple selectors in the first place will be quite a challenge. I'll add a barebones pseudo-code solution in a moment. In the meantime I'll leave my answer quoting the spec first. Editing as we speak.

Comment: I made my answer community wiki. If you or anyone else comes up with actual JavaScript implementation, we'd love to see it!

Comment: @BoltClock: While searching around, I found a PHP implementation http://www.suzyit.com/tools/specificity.php?source . I will try and create the JS implementation and edit the wiki if possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [the Selectors level 3 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#specificity):

> A selector's specificity is calculated as follows:
>
> - count the number of ID selectors in the selector (= a)
> - count the number of class selectors, attributes selectors, and pseudo-classes in the selector (= b)
> - count the number of type selectors and pseudo-elements in the selector (= c)
> - ignore the universal selector
>
> Selectors inside the negation pseudo-class [`:not()`] are counted like any other, but the negation itself does not count as a pseudo-class.
>
> Concatenating the three numbers a-b-c (in a number system with a large base) gives the specificity.
>
> Examples:
>
> ```css
> *               /* a=0 b=0 c=0 -> specificity =   0 */
> LI              /* a=0 b=0 c=1 -> specificity =   1 */
> UL LI           /* a=0 b=0 c=2 -> specificity =   2 */
> UL OL+LI        /* a=0 b=0 c=3 -> specificity =   3 */
> H1 + *[REL=up]  /* a=0 b=1 c=1 -> specificity =  11 */
> UL OL LI.red    /* a=0 b=1 c=3 -> specificity =  13 */
> LI.red.level    /* a=0 b=2 c=1 -> specificity =  21 */
> #x34y           /* a=1 b=0 c=0 -> specificity = 100 */
> #s12:not(FOO)   /* a=1 b=0 c=1 -> specificity = 101 */
> ```

([Selectors level 4](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-4/#specificity), published after this answer, adds another layer of complexity to specificity thanks to the introduction of some new selectors that is currently outside this answer's scope.)

Here's a pseudocode implementation to get you started, it is nowhere near perfect but I hope it's a reasonable starting point:

```js
function SortByCssSpecificity(selectors, element) {
    simple_selectors = [][]
    for selector in selectors {
        // Optionally pass an element to only include selectors that match
        // The implementation of MatchSelector() is outside the scope
        // of this answer, but client-side JS can use Element#matches()
        // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches
        if (element && !MatchSelector(selector, element)) {
            continue
        }

        simple_selectors[selector] = ParseSelector(selector)
        simple_selectors[selector] = simple_selectors[selector].filter(x | x != '*')

        // This assumes pseudo-elements are denoted with double colons per CSS3
        // A conforming implementation must interpret
        // :first-line, :first-letter, :before and :after as pseudo-elements
        a = simple_selectors[selector].filter(x | x ^= '#').length
        b = simple_selectors[selector].filter(x | x ^= '.' or x.match(/^:[^:]+/) or x.match(/^\[.+\]$/)).length
        c = simple_selectors[selector].length - (a + b)

        simple_selectors[selector][count] = parseInt('' + a + b + c)
    }

    return simple_selectors.sort(x, y | x[count] < y[count])
}

function ParseSelector(selector) {
    simple_selectors = []
    // Split by the group operator ','
    // Split each selector group by combinators ' ', '+', '~', '>'
    // :not() is a special case, do not include it as a pseudo-class

    // For the selector div > p:not(.foo) ~ span.bar,
    // sample output is ['div', 'p', '.foo', 'span', '.bar']
    return simple_selectors
}
```

Comment: And, my favourite surprise, it's counting with repetition: `a.foo.foo` (21) is more specific than `a.foo` (11).

Comment: @BoltClock I think that the function SortByCssSpecificity(selectors) need to be corrected with SortByCssSpecificity(selectors, node) because some CSS selector text might not be relevant for the node. For instance, with the group operater `,`. Some CSS selector text isn't relevant to the node so, they shouldn't be counted.

Comment: @einstein: Don't know how I missed your comment for 9 years, but I've added that functionality now, though it wasn't in the original question. I did rename node to element for the sake of accuracy - not all nodes are element nodes, and selectors will only match element nodes.