# find out specificity of a css selector in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-specificity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sorting a set of CSS selectors on the basis of specificity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5158631/sorting-a-set-of-css-selectors-on-the-basis-of-specificity)

does anyone know of a way to find out the specificity of a css selector in javascript? is there some library or maybe even browser support? I hoped jquery would provide something but as far as I looked at the source/docs I didn't find anything.

it would be not to hard to write one on my own but I would prefer a proven solution. a css selector parser would also be useful.

I need it to sort a set of rules which match the same element by specificity.

specificity as in http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#specificity