# Is there an JS library that orders CSS selector texts according to specificity?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-selectors, css-specificity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sorting a set of CSS selectors on the basis of specificity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5158631/sorting-a-set-of-css-selectors-on-the-basis-of-specificity)

I need a JS library that order CSS selector texts from most specific selector text to the less specific selector text, where specificity is specified according to [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#specificity)

If there aren't any libraries out there, could I write it pretty simply using JS or jQuery?

CSS selector text could be `div#body .text`.

Comment: What is *'specificty'* exactly?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan, it's [defined by spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#specificity).

Comment: Woho87, it's not clear what you're looking for - do you want a debugging tool that will show you a list of all the rules that are being applied to a particular element, in order from most to least specific? Or something totally different? (Also, I fixed the spelling to 'specificity' from 'specificty'.)

Comment: Can you explain what exactly you want? I'm afraid this question will be closed without this info.

Comment: I don't want any debugging tool. I'm creating a debugging tool:) I just need a library that order selector texts from most specific selector text to the less specific selector text, where specificity is specified according to http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#specificity

Comment: Ok updated the text. I hope you get it.

Comment: question makes no mention of what this library should do, or how it would be used

Comment: @charlietfl: "what this library should do" is plastered all over the question, especially after the edit...

Comment: @BoltClock notify my when you write one yourself.

Comment: My comment got auto-deleted, reposting: unfortunately all I have in the duplicate question is a rough pseudo-code solution, and no implementation details. I haven't heard of any libraries that do this yet, so I may very well end up writing one myself soon.

Answer (score 1):

In the comments on your question, josh3736 links [the W3C specification for determining specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#specificity).  If you felt inclined to write such a library yourself (which I'd encourage, if for no other reason than learning more about it), their method seems like a good reference.

> A selector's specificity is calculated as follows:
>
> - count 1 if the declaration is from is a 'style' attribute rather than a rule with a selector, 0 otherwise (= a) (In HTML, values of an element's "style" attribute are style sheet rules. These rules have no selectors, so a=1, b=0, c=0, and d=0.)
> - count the number of ID attributes in the selector (= b)
> - count the number of other attributes and pseudo-classes in the selector (= c)
> - count the number of element names and pseudo-elements in the selector (= d)
>
> The specificity is based only on the form of the selector. In particular, a selector of the form "[id=p33]" is counted as an attribute selector (a=0, b=0, c=1, d=0), even if the id attribute is defined as an "ID" in the source document's DTD.
>
> Concatenating the four numbers a-b-c-d (in a number system with a large base) gives the specificity.

Comment: I might be writing this myself. But I need to make sure that others haven't wrote it yet :)

Answer (score 1):

I figured I'd give this a stab.  Feel free to use, modify (or fix) this code as you see fit. I can't promise it's correct, but the examples they give on the w3c spec all produce the same results.

```
function specificity(selector, isStyleAttribute) {

    selector = selector || "";
    function numMatches(regex) {
        return (selector.match(regex)||[]).length;
    }

    var numClasses = numMatches(/\.[\w-_]+\b/g);
    var numIds = numMatches(/#[\w-_]+\b/g);
    var numNamesInBraces = 0;
    var namesInBraces = selector.match(/\[[^\]]*\b[\w-_]+\b[^\]]*\]/g) || [];
    for (var idx = 0; idx < namesInBraces.length; ++idx) {
        numNamesInBraces += (namesInBraces[idx].match(/\b[\w-_]+\b/g)||[]).length;
    }

    var results = [0,0,0,0];
    results[0] = isStyleAttribute ? 1 : 0;
    results[1] = numIds;
    results[2] = numMatches(/\[[^\]]+\]/g) + numClasses;
    results[3] = numMatches(/\b[\w-_]+\b/g) - numIds - numClasses - numNamesInBraces;
    return results.join(',');

}
```

If you want to sort an array with it, it can be used like this:

```
selectors.sort(function(a,b) { return specificity(a) > specificity(b); });
```

Comment: Inline styles don't have selectors - you would have to pass nothing as the first parameter and skip all of these checks altogether. In the duplicate question I link to, I provide a skeleton which covers most of the parts, but then again I might end up implementing something completely different from what I had originally planned...

Comment: I can merge your answer into the other question if you'd like.